# The relation between Internal Pressure and flow rate in a balloon

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure

I'm working on a project. We have two balloons, connected by a hose with a valve.We know when we open the valve, by according to internal pressure of each balloon, air goes form the higher pressure balloon to lower pressure  balloon. I want to know the relation between internal pressure of the balloons and the flow rate between these two balloons. Pay attention, I **don't** want the air transfer direction, I want the **FLOW RATE**.

Thanks.

Comment: If velocity flow is low enough, the Hagen–Poiseuille equation will work http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hagen%E2%80%93Poiseuille_equation . Also check http://oac.med.jhmi.edu/res_phys/Encyclopedia/AirFlow/AirFlow.HTML if you don't understand something, make your question more specific

Answer (score 0):

If you know electric stuff, this will help:  Pressure is like voltage, air flow is like current.  A pressure difference in the two balloons is like a voltage difference.  The tube and valve connecting the balloons has a "resistance" to air flow.  The air flow between the baloons will be $F = (P2-P1)/R$ where $F$ is the air flow rate, $P2$ and $P1$ are the pressures in the two balloons, and $R$ is the resistance to air flow of the tube and valve between the two balloons.

What is $R$?  Exercise left to the reader.  Given what I'm telling you, you can think of a few ways of measuring it, and even determine what its units are.  But I will point out the following:

1. $R$ is higher for a thin tube, lower for a wide tube.
2. $R$ is higher for a long tube, lower for a short tube.
3. If the valve has large uninterrupted room for airflow through it, it won't increase $R$ much, if it is more restrictive than the tubes, it will dominate $R$.